# Combined Business and Tourism Trip to Schengen Area. Which consulate am I supposed to approach for a visa?

Tags: france, schengen-visas, applications, iceland, itineraries

I am traveling to France for X days on a business event and following that am going on a vacation trip to Iceland where I will be staying for X+6 days and X+5 nights.

As I understand the procedures for visa applications, I should send my application to:

- France consulate -- as the main purpose of my trip is the French business meeting, and France is my port of entry to Schengen.
- Iceland consulate (taken care of by the Denmark consulate) -- as I spend more days of my travel in Iceland.

According the the Schengen rules and guidelines for visa applications (and those of France & Iceland), to which consulate should I send my application? Does it matter (according to the official rules and guidelines)?

(*Note: To keep this question from being too opinion based, let's limit it to what the official rules and guidelines say, rather than speculating on what will happen in my particular case.*)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "no one knows if the consulate will approve or reject the application"

Comment: No-one can say for sure. You appear to be meeting the requirements of Article 5 https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf#page18 It’s normal to combine a business trip with a vacation, however Iceland is sometimes viewed as one of the ‘easier’ Schengen visas to obtain so if they think you’ve contrived your itinerary to increase your chance of success it’s possible you could be rejected. Hopefully your evidence supporting both your business trip and vacation is sound.

Comment: I have made an edit to hopefully reopen this question  -- the core of this question (to what consulate one should apply, and what happens if you apply to the wrong one) can be answered without resort to opinion or speculation as to what will happen in this particular case.

Answer (score 5):

The "longest stay" rule applies only if no main purpose for your trip can be identified, so as far as I can see you should have applied to France instead.

If the Danish consulate has this opinion too, they should return the application to you undecided and refund the application fee -- in other words, you won't get a visa, but you also won't have a visa *refusal* that you'll need to explain later. You can then immediately apply to France instead.

On the other hand, there's nothing much you can do now other than wait and hope they *don't* share my understanding of the rule.

Comment: ...and, if they do, simply submit an application to France.